# Connect to remote Docker Daemon

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I have a Windows 10 Home machine (local machine) where I have installed Docker Toolbox that runs docker inside a VM. IP (192.168.0.6)

Also, there is another Windows 10 Pro machine (remote machine) that has Docker Desktop installed. IP (192.168.0.13). In the Docker Desktop setting, I have enabled "Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS". At this point, I do not care about the TLS part since both the machines are on the local network. In the firewall setting, I have accepted inbound connections from port 2375.

Now I would like to run docker-compose from a local machine that connects and runs docker on the remote machine. To test connection, the command used on local machine is

```
docker -H tcp://192.168.0.13:2375 version
```

The response is

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://192.168.0.13:2375. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I see that it calls `https://192.168.0.13:2375/v1.40/info` and not `http://192.168.0.13:2375`.

And in my remote machine, if I enter `http://localhost:2375/v1.40/info` I get a response but there is no response when I run by providing IP like `http://192.168.0.13:2375/v1.40/info`

Answer (score 0):

I assume your docker daemon is only listening on `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

You try to connect from another machine which connects to your machine with you internal network ip `192.168.0.13`.

---

This means you need to configure your docker daemon to listen to:

> `192.168.0.13` = only network internal

`tcp://192.168.0.13:2375`

> `0.0.0.0` = all ip addresses

`tcp://0.0.0.0:2375`

---

In Windows you need to create a Docker-Daemon config file in:

`C:\ProgramData\docker\config\daemon.json`

with following content:

```
{
    "hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:2376"] # IP Address for container host
}
```

---

You can probably define a Subnet but i am not sure about this.

Comment: Yes, the first step would be to listen to Internal network IP from the remote machine itself. But I do not know how to achieve that.

Comment: Adding the value in daemon.json prevents Docker Desktop from starting.

Comment: There is a debug option which is also an optional part in the json: `"debug": true`. Maybe this helps you. Because the above mentioned configuration is from the official documentation.

Comment: Adding hosts no longer works in the latest version of Docker for Windows. They have blocked [“hosts”] from being used in docker desktop that runs on hyper-v back end.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the VM network interface is only binded to your localhost.
Try forwarding the port. From powershell or command prompt with admin privileges:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=2375 listenaddress=192.168.0.13 connectaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=2375
```